# Javascript if else beginner

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Could someone give me a hint what is wrong here?

```js
var age = 18;
prompt('please add your age...');
if (age > 18) {
  alert("Welcome.");
}
if (age < 18) {
  alert("You are not allowed..");
}
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific, what isn't working? What is the input you are using? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @MattiPrice A few things are too obvious... You don't need to explain. Just saying.. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't assigning the input to the `age` variable, but you are setting it to `18`, which is not covered by your if or else. Few things you need to do:

1. Please assign the variable to the user given value.
2. Check for equality too. What if the user gives `18`?
3. Also, using `else if` would be a better candidate here.

Your final code should be:

```js
// Change below.
var age = prompt('please add your age...');
// Change condition below.
if (age >= 18) {
  alert("Welcome.");
} else if (age < 18) { // Use else if.
  alert("You are not allowed..");
}
```

Comment: Using `else` would be even better.

Comment: @Barmar I was using it before, and thought of this... LoL. You are right. My bad... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
// var age = 18
// prompt('please add your age...') // this prompts but isnt doing anything with the returned value. try
var age = prompt('please add your age...')

if (age > 18) {
  alert('Welcome.')
}
if (age < 18) {
  alert('You are not allowed..')
}
if (age === 18) {
  alert('this is true')
}
```

Neither of your conditions were true. Age WAS 18, but you were checking if age was above of below 18.

Also if you wanted to assign the user input value to age, the prompt function returns that value into the age variable like above.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable for your prompt input.

```js
const age = 18; 
const value = prompt('please add your age...');

if (age > value) {
    alert("Welcome.");
}
else if (age < value) {        
    alert("You are not allowed..");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const age=prompt('please add your age...');
if (age > 18) alert("Welcome.");
else alert("You are not allowed.");
```